# Powershell: Using Foreach for Get-EC2Snapshot

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, foreach

I got a script with the variable `$volumeNames` in it, which has some Volume-IDs `vol-11111 vol-2222 ...` in it.

Now I am trying to process all those IDs in another command using `foreach`, but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
$AllSnapshots = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($volume in $volumeNames) {
Get-EC2Snapshot -OwnerId $AWSAccount | Where-Object {$_.VolumeId -eq $Volume}
    }
Write-Output "Total number of snapshots: $AllSnapshots.Count"
```

Comment: Please paste exact format of what is contained in that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$AllSnapshots = foreach ($volume in $volumeNames) {
    Get-EC2Snapshot -OwnerId $AWSAccount | Where-Object {$_.VolumeId -eq $Volume}
}

Write-Output "Total number of snapshots: $($AllSnapshots.Count)"
```

This should result in `$AllSnapshots` being a collection of snapshot objects returned by `Get-EC2Snapshot`.

Alternatively you could do:

```
$AllSnapshots = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($volume in $volumeNames) {
     $AllSnapshots += Get-EC2Snapshot -OwnerId $AWSAccount | Where-Object {$_.VolumeId -eq $Volume}
}

Write-Output "Total number of snapshots: $($AllSnapshots.Count)"
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!